# USB device not visible in virtualbox under 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, usb, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 and I installed Virtualbox as follows

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ext-pack
sudo adduser newbie vboxusers
```

I then installed `XP/SP3` and it booted ok, `mouse` and `tty` function ok
when I connect a `USB2-stick` to my host it shows up in the host
when I start Oracle VM Virtualbox Manager the stick does not show up in
`Settings>XPSP3>USB`.

I have `Enable USB Controoler` and `USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller` switched on. Since two years I am also running Ubuntu 14.04 with `Sun VM` and an `XPSP3 virtualmachine` and there the USB works fine. I have read all similar questions tagged `virtualbox` and `usb` but found no solution

Comment: I think that you need to make a USB filter to pass the USB through the host to the guest.

Comment: Did you reboot your Host machine after adding the user to the group? If not, please do it, and try again.

Comment: Did you install virtualbox guest additions on the guest machine? Because if you haven't, you won't be able to present an usb drive to it.

Comment: Thanks Arronical, something went wrong defining the filter,  it works fine now.  By the way, How can I close this question, my problem is solved